# JSF method of f:event preRenderView called after c:forEach

Tags: jsf-2, jstl

I'm doing a page with jsf 2.0 and i wanna do something like this:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="${id}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{controller.initPage(id)}"/>
</f:metadata>
....(Some code)....
<c:forEach items="#{bean.listLoadedByInitPage}" var="var">
    #{var.something}
</c:forEach>
```

The method *initPage(id)* must load list in the bean. But seems that method is called after than *c:forEach* loads items not before. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JSTL tags runs during **view build** time. The `<f:event type="preRenderView">` runs right before **view render** time. In other words, `<c:forEach>` runs before `<f:event>`. So, this behaviour is fully expected.

You have 2 options:

1. Use `@ManagedProperty` instead of `<f:viewParam>`, or when the bean is in the view scope or broader, grab it manually from `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()` inside `@PostConstruct`. And, use `@PostConstruct` instead of `<f:event type="preRenderView">`. Yes, this makes the entire `<f:metadata>` obsolete. You can safely remove it.
2. Use a JSF component instead of `<c:forEach>` tag, such as `<ui:repeat>`.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/)